# Android Studio can't find JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't seem to get my Android applications to compile due to a really annoying exception from Android Studio:

[image: ]()![enter image description here]

```
Execution failed for task ':myapp-services:compileDebugJava'.
    Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm running Oracle's Java 7 JRE/JDK.

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/"
```

In `android-studio/bin/studio.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/"
```

Output of `javac -version`:

```
javac 1.7.0_51
```

Output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Output of `printenv JAVA_HOME`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Output of `which javac`:

```
/usr/bin/javac
```

I have also logged out and logged back in again to my session.

I'm really not sure what I'm missing here. Why can't Android Studio compile my application?

Comment: what is the output if you try `printenv JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Added those to the question, they seem to be normal.

Comment: based on the output from `which javac` maybe you don't really have the JDK installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`.  Is `/usr/bin/javac` a symlink?  (to where?)

Comment: Found the solution, see answer.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is set to JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1 but android studio produces an error on startup. That directory is valid on my system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution in [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054900/128967):

```
rm ~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/jdk.table.xml
```

What seems to have happened is that something was configured for a previous version of Android Studio and this configuration lived too long :)

Comment: Brilliant! For me it was  ~/.AndroidStudioBeta/config/options/jdk.table.xml but that's the same principle. I switched from opensdk to oracle jdk and couldn't compile anymore. Note that you need to restart studio in order to re-index and make it work.

Comment: On Windows, this is C:\Users\<your_logon_name>\.AndroidStudio<your_version>\config\options\jdk.table.xml, but removing it still didn't fix the error.

Comment: I guess because my error starts with "Error:Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.".

Answer (score 16):

I solved it by updating build.gradle (Top-Level) with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

Comment: in my case `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error too. After many hours trying to solve it, I've managed to solve the problem.

In my case, executing the app from command line did the trick!

Here's what I did (I'm using Windows 10). Please, run these commands on the root of the project (where we have the **app** directory):

1) **gradlew assembleDebug**

- Gradle will execute its tasks and you should see the message: **BUILD SUCCESSFUL**

2) **adb install -r app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk**

- After executing this line, you'll see the message:
  **[100%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug-unaligned.apk
      pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug-unaligned.apk
  Success**

3) **adb shell am start -n package_name/package_name.MainActivity**, where "package_name" must be replaced by your package name (you can find it on AndroidManifest.xml). If "MainActivity" is not your launcher activity, replace it by your own activity.

- You'll see the message: **Starting: Intent { cmp=package_name/.MainActivity }**, where "package_name" is your app' package name.

It will install the app on your device and after that, Android Studio seems to find the JAVA_HOME variable again. You should be able to run the app by hitting the "Run" button on Android Studio.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by updating classpath of (build.gradle (Project:projectName))

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

Go To Settings->Project Structure->JDK path and change it to the system JDK instead of Studio JDK, you will be up and running.

Answer (score 1):

**update build.gradle module**

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded the latest version (android-studio-ide-1641136.dmg) and I just changed the Info.plist file content. It's originally configured to use 1.6* as of Java version. I have 1.8 installed, so just changed to 1.8* and worked.

I am on Mac Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem with the Android Studio studio.bat file 
and here it is

```
    ::------------------------------------------------------
    :: Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
    :: Try (in order): ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK, ..\jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME.
    :: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXIST "%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%" SET JDK=%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%~dp0\..\jre" SET JDK=%~dp0\..\jre
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%JDK_HOME%" SET JDK=%JDK_HOME%
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
    IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error
```

Do you get the problem in the last 2 lines of code?
It seems that if your environmental variable is %JAVA_HOME% the batch file will GOTO error and an error message will be displayed and that's it NO ANDROID STUDIO FOR YOU, even though %JAVA_HOME% contains a valid path but if the environmental variable is something like %ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK% like mine is because I created it myself then it will work

---

#### PROPOSED SOLUTIONS

(1) Edit the batch file
Where you see this
`IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error` 
Change it to this
`IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error` 
(2) Create an environmental variable named %ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
as shown here
https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500

Answer (score 0):

Check **echo $JAVA_HOME**

if it doesn't gives you correct path. follow [setting JAVA_HOME path on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287542/setting-java-home-path-on-ubuntu)

if it gives you correct path set then you need to update your gradle plugin version (It worked for me) and rebuild project.